# Trying to add facebooksdk.jar file to my project

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have installed facebookSDK and the sample apps.  The sample apps all copilr and run fine.

I tried to make my own app.  The only thing I did was creat a new android project, test it, runs fine.  Then I added the  facebooksdk jar file.  Now my project no longer runs and I get a error that says

> “jar miss match fix your dependencies”

The jar file seed to load in correctly, if I click on android dependences I see
Facebooksdk.jar ../programming/facebooksdk/……

I tried to see what was different from my project ans facebook's sample code.
Under android dependencies it had the same line I had Facebooksdk.jar ../programming/facebooksdk/……

And also had another jar file called android-suppert-v4-.jar that I do not have.

Other then that both the sample code and my test project seem to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

there is a jar that exists both in the facebook sdk project and in yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by having a duplicate jar -- a .jar file of the same name that appears in both projects, but is not the exact same file. In this case, it is probably android.support.v4.jar, since Facebook uses it, and your project likely does too.

Check your dependencies carefully (and check your assets, bin, etc. folders) for the android support library in your own project -- even if you didn't add it yourself, the dependency could have been added by default, especially if you used the wizards provided with ADT for eclipse.